# Slow application while scrolling through the table

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-data, asynchronous, uiimageview

I am new to mobile development. In my application I've got a table which shows the recipes created by the user. A cell is designed as a nib-file with an image (which is asynchronously loaded) and 2 labels. Everything seems ok on the simulator. But scrolling through the table looks horrible on a real device even after implementation of asynchronous loading of images. 
While using time profiler that most of the time is occupied by the main function. So I'm thinking whether this may be caused by using core data. I'm not sure about this.
I would be grateful if anyone could help me with this issue.

This is actually how I fill my cell with data:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"TableCell";
    SimpleTableViewCell *cell = (SimpleTableViewCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    Receipe *cellRecipe = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.recipeName.text = cellRecipe.name;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:cellRecipe.image];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [cell.recipeImage setImage:image];
        });
    });

    cell.recipeDetails.text = cellRecipe.ingredients;

    UIImage *favourite;
    if ([cellRecipe.isFavourite boolValue] == YES) {
        favourite = [UIImage imageNamed:@"liked.png"];
    }

    [cell.recipeIsFavouriteButton setImage:favourite forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    favourite = nil;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Please add to your question your tableview datasource methods and your code that makes the image request.

Comment: This clunky nib file loading code isn't needed anymore. u should register a nib with the tableview and use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`

Comment: What does the Time Profiler in instruments tell you?  What lines of code are taking up the most time?  Start there.  Share the profile if you want but that is step one.  Otherwise people are just guessing (badly).

Comment: This is what the profiler shows me http://postimg.org/image/mtycxcscj/

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

instead of

```
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
```

> I think there is no need for Asynchronous loading, use normal loading.

Comment: I did that but that didn't save the app from slow table scrolling(

Comment: did you try normal loading instead of Asynchronous?

Comment: also add `[[cell.contentView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];` in your code to remove subviews from superviews

Comment: yes, I started with it. And now, after you wrote this, I decided to return to simple loading which looks better after all. But the problem didn't disappear. I'll try to remove subviews now